# sockets question

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-thread

i have a server and client classes but the problem is: when i make infinite loop to accept incoming connection i cant receive all the data received from the client while accepting the connections because accept blocks until the connection is accepted, my code:

```
    for (;;) 
    {
       boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&Irc::Server::startAccept, &s));
       thread.join();
       for (ClientsMap::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) 
       {
          std::string msg = getData(it->second->recv());
          std::clog << "Msg: " << msg << std::endl;
       }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of starting a thread and joining it immediately?

Comment: i thought join waits for the thread to finish?

Comment: It does, which means only one thread is running at a time, totally defeating the purpose.

Comment: Rather than using a `Boost::thread` along with (apparently) some other socket code, have you looked at using ASIO (or is that what your `IRC::Server::startAccept` already using)?

Comment: im using normal sockets, but actually i got this problem with asio too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either multiple threads or a call to `select`/`poll` to find out which connections have unprocessed data.  [IBM has a nice example here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/example.htm), which will work on any flavor of Unix, Linux, BSD, etc. (you might need different header files depending on the OS).

Right now you're starting a thread and then waiting for it immediately, which results in sequential execution and completely defeats the purpose of threads.

Comment: how am i supposed to do that, can you give me an example?

Comment: Here's an example using select, I'm still looking for a good one with poll, which is the newer better option: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html#Server-Example

Comment: Here's an example with `poll`, error handling, the whole works: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/example.htm

Comment: That said, I usually end up not using either the raw `poll` API or the cross-platform `boost::asio` wrapper, because they only allow you to do I/O on a bunch of sockets (on some platforms, files as well).  I usually end up using the event-driven socket functions of my UI toolkit (on Windows, `WSAAsyncSelect`, on Unix, `XtAppAddInput`) and that way a single thread can respond to network requests and user interaction in a clean event-driven way.  It's a little more work (really not much) to set up the event callbacks, but it prevents race conditions by design.

Comment: But that's just my preference, since I like my servers to have a little control UI showing how many connections, an exit button, stuff like that.  For system services that run in the background, the `poll` API by itself works really well.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to create one thread that only accepts new connections. That's where you have a listener socket. Then, for every connection that gets accepted, you have a new connected socket, so you can spawn another thread, giving it the connected socket as a parameter. That way, your thread that accepts connections doesn't get blocked, and can connect to many clients very fast. The processing threads deal with the clients and then they exit.

I don't even know why need to wait for them, but if you do, you may deal with it in some other way, depending on the OS and/or libraries that you use (messages, signals etc can be used).

If you don't want to spawn a new thread for each connected client, then as Ben Voigt suggested, you can use select. That is another good approach if you want to make it single threaded. Basically, all your sockets will be in an array of socket descriptors and using select you will know what happened (someone connected, socket is ready for read/write, socket got disconnected etc) and act accordingly.

Here's one example Partial one, but it works. you just accept connections in the acceptConnections(), which will then spawn a separate thread for each client. That's where you communicate with the clients. It's from a windows code that i have lying around, but it's very easy to be reimplemented for any platform.

```
typedef struct SOCKET_DATA_ {
  SOCKET sd;
  /* other parameters that you may want to pass to the clientProc */
} SOCKET_DATA;

/* In this function you communicate with the clients */
DWORD WINAPI clientProc(void * param)
{
    SOCKET_DATA * pSocketData = (SOCKET_DATA *)param;

    /* Communicate with the new client, and at the end deallocate the memory for
       SOCKET_DATA and return.
    */

    delete pSocketData;
    return 0;
}

int acceptConnections(const char * pcAddress, int nPort)
{
    sockaddr_in sinRemote;
    int nAddrSize;
    SOCKET sd_client;
    SOCKET sd_listener;
    sockaddr_in sinInterface;
    SOCKET_DATA * pSocketData;
    HANDLE hThread;

    sd_listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (INVALID_SOCKET == sd_listener) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get a listener socket!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sinInterface.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sinInterface.sin_port = nPort;
    sinInterface.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (SOCKET_ERROR != bind(sd_listener, (sockaddr*)&sinInterface, sizeof(sockaddr_in))) {
        listen(sd_listener, SOMAXCONN);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind the listening socket!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        nAddrSize = sizeof(sinRemote);
        sd_client = accept(sd_listener, (sockaddr*)&sinRemote, &nAddrSize);

        if (INVALID_SOCKET == sd_client) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Accept failed!\n");
            closesocket(sd_listener);
            return 1;
        }

        fprintf(stdout, "Accepted connection from %s:%u.\n", inet_ntoa(sinRemote.sin_addr), ntohs(sinRemote.sin_port));
        pSocketData = (SOCKET_DATA *)malloc(sizeof(SOCKET_DATA));

        if (!pSocketData) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for SOCKET_DATA!\n");
            return 1;
        }

        pSocketData->sd = sd_client;
        hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, clientProc, pSocketData, 0, &nThreadID);

        if (hThread == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while trying to create a thread!\n");
            delete pSocketData;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    closesocket(sd_listener);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The good thing about one thread per client, is that it's easy to keep track of independent state per-client.  However, scheduling all the threads is not as efficient as `poll`, and if you have data shared between clients it's very easy to introduce race conditions (and adding mutexes or other synchronization to fix the race conditions will make performance even worse).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

especially the **HTTP Server 3** example, thats exactly what you are looking for , all you have to do is change that code a little bit for your needs :) and your done

Comment: yes of course, each end every asynchronous operation is a non blocking operation. In most of the cases when you use async operations(functions) you don't even have to use threads at all, this can simplify your design + removes the added overhead of some context switching caused by added threads

Comment: An HTTP server, where connections serve requests almost completely independently of one another, isn't all that great a foundation to use for a chat server.  But that `boost::asio` page also has a chat example.